# How to configure RAD7.5 to use some predefined filters

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, rad, websphere-6.1

I am using RAD7.5 for the project development. My web.xml file looks like this:

```
 <context-param>
  <param-name>config.file</param-name>
  <param-value>@project.config.location@</param-value>
</context-param>
```

So basically @project.config.location@ is retrieved from a properties file(config.properties) during the ant-build process using the filterset code as shown below:

```
<copy todir="${project.build.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${web.project.webcontent.dir}" excludes="**/classes/**" />
        <filterset>
            <filtersfile file="${web.project.src.dir}/filters/${file.filter.name}" />
        </filterset>

    </copy>
```

So my problem is how to configure RAD7.5 so that while deploying the app locally(right click on the project EAR -> run on server) will replace these filters. I have been trying to find the solution but could not find anything on the web yet.Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

maybe to have ant builder in properties->builders of your project? On the other way RAD itself edit and managed web.xml, so if you prefer RAD process, design your app without ant.

Answer (score 0):

This project was designed in the other IDE which dealt with ANT. Also I cannot change the process because ANT is the standard builder for the company, when it comes to deploy the project.All the configuration managers use Ant.I just want to make it compatible with both the options. I liked your first suggestion i.e. to have ant builder in properties->builders of your project. How do I do that. I did this so far... Right Click on the project->Properties->Builders. I wanted only to apply that filter while deploying the app.So since I want to keep @....@ filters in my web.xml. Is there a way to tell RAD when It is deploying the app to the server just apply that filter(shown below) process on it's way(I just want to modify the default deploy process in the RAD):

```
<filterset>
                <filtersfile file="${web.project.src.dir}/filters/${file.filter.name}" />
            </filterset>
```